# Alternative to Stored Procedures

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, web-hosting

I use a web host who say that everytime i want to execute a stored procedure, i have to email their support team and they will grant permission for me to use it for the first time, (no guarantee of timescales or anything) are there any alternatives to stored procedures that i can use to speed up displaying 5000+ records from a mysql DB?

Comment: Where is the problem to display 5000 records from the DB?

Comment: It practically crashes the browser then displays them after a 10 second wait, i'm not on slow broadband either. But i am just doing a basic php script, connect, select * from table, display in a table...

Comment: I guess you are using while ($row = ..) { echo "Each Row data"; }. So do like this:
ob_start(); while ($row = ... ) { echo "Each Row data"; } ob_end_flush();

Comment: yup! this sort of thing: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {  
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['project_no'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['cust_name'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
      }

Comment: So, my above comment will surely help you. Check the ob_start(); and ob_end_flush(); on the comment. And I read it here about stored procedure (http://goo.gl/534wn), it is not much about speed. So just implement the solution and chill down.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You asked the wrong question here. It has nothing to do with alternative to stored procedures. Pass two additional params LIMIT, OFFSET as params and will return only what you have told in LIMIT

Comment: Yes but i need to display 5000 records.

Comment: I don't want to question the logic you have, but probably it's just too much to display all 5000. Make it like Facebook does, when you reach to the bottom of the preloaded X records you load another set of X records. No one wants to wait while browsing to download 5000 items. You need to display them dynamically when the user needs.